# iOS - Present viewcontroller from another presented viewcontroller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uivewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers, **A**, **B** and **C**. **B** is presented on **A**. What I need is to present **C** on **A** when a button clicked on **B** and dismiss **B**. But I am unable to do so. Is there some workaround. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you want to happen to B at this point?

Comment: B should be dismissed.

Comment: Using a delegate setup, have B send a message to A (via the delegate) indicating that A should dismiss B and then display C.

Comment: A is not a single viewcontroller. B can be presented on any viewcontroller of my application. It is good idea to setup delegate in a parent viewcontroller and extend others from it but due to specific kind of application, I cant extend all viewcontrollers to single viewcontroller.

Comment: `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` - the completion could work to your advantage in this situation

Comment: Jugale I have tried this but it also not working in this case.

Comment: Once the view controller B is dismissed, present the view controller C after some delay (0.5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click the button on B, in iOS5,

```
UIViewController *presentingVC = self.presentingViewController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
      [presentingVC presentViewController:vc3 animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

when you clicked the button on B, pop B itself and use NSNotificationCenter  to gave a notification to A,make A to push C.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to setup a delegate just get A through the property presentingViewController inside B, call the desired method of A, in that method first dismiss modal controller and then present C.